# Trim string based on characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, split

I have strings like

```
WebApp - 10148

Smart - App - 1458
```

**Expected Result**

```
WebApp

Smart - App
```

I want to trim the characters from - to numbers from right.

I have tried the below query and the result is this

```
select LEFT(app+' - ', CHARINDEX(' - ',app+' - ')-1) from repository

WebApp
Smart
```

Can anyone assist me to sort this?

Comment: `app` is the name of the column containig the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
reverse(right(reverse(@string), len(@string) - charindex('-',reverse(@string),1)));
```

Comment: looks great! can I tweak the hyphen at the end?

Comment: @Michael:- Updated, now you will not get the hyphen at the end. Please check now!

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun one approach with rekursive CTE (I'd use Rahul's answer :-)  )

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(x VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('WebApp - 10148'),('Smart - App - 1458');

WITH FindHyphens AS
(
    SELECT x,0 AS StartInx, PATINDEX('% - %',x) AS PosHyphen,SUBSTRING(x,PATINDEX('% - %',x)+1,1000) AS Subst FROM @tbl
    UNION ALL
    SELECT x,StartInx+PATINDEX('% - %',Subst),PATINDEX('% - %',Subst),SUBSTRING(Subst,PATINDEX('% - %',Subst)+1,1000)
    FROM FindHyphens
    WHERE PATINDEX('% - %',Subst)>0
)
,FindLastHyphen AS
(
    SELECT x, MAX(StartInx+PosHyphen)-1 AS LastPos
    FROM FindHyphens
    GROUP BY x
)
SELECT SUBSTRING(x,1,LastPos)
FROM FindLastHyphen
```